How is this z-loss implementation in t5x related to this paper's loss X?
I was looking into the loss function in t5x here and see there is a z-loss added to the typical log loss definition.
The only paper I could surface on this was https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08859, but I don't see the correlation. In the code, it is logsumexp of the logits squared.
But in the paper it is calculating mean/variance for the z-loss you can see the author's implementation here.
I am asking for help either connecting the two or looking for resources on the current implementation if they are in fact unrelated.

Could you please reformulate the title as a question? Like "How is this z-loss implementation in t5x related to this paper's loss X?"

Sure, I changed it.
